# save entry values for next programmstart tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

thanks a lot for your time. I'm currently stuck at the following point: I have developed a GUI with Tkinter with about 200 entries. (For simplification I have only included a small section below). But these 200 entries are seldom filled in at once. Normally 50 entries are filled in every start of the program. When the program is closed, these filled in values are deleted and have to be filled in again after the program is started again. Is there a way to prevent this?

I do not want to lose the values entered in jobNameA_entry and jobNameB_entry when closing the program.

Many thanks in any case.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Win1:
    

    def __init__(self, master):
        
        
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Gap Assessment")
        self.topFrame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.topFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news', ipady = 5)
        self.A_GapFrame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.B_GapFrame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.subframe_AGap()
        self.subframe_BGap()  
        
        # Create a Tkinter variable
        self.gapType = tk.StringVar(self.master)
        # Dictionary with optionsverschwinden
        self.choiceGap =  ['AFrame','BFrame']
        # self.choiceGap = sorted(self.choiceGap)
        self.gapType.set('') # set the default option
        self.ctngMenu = tk.OptionMenu(self.topFrame, self.gapType, *self.choiceGap, command=self.chioseGap_handle)
        self.ctngMenu.grid(row = 1, column =2)

    def chioseGap_handle(self, selected):
        
        if selected == 'AFrame':
            self.A_GapFrame.tkraise()
            # self.subframe_AGap()
            self.A_GapFrame.place(x=20, y=30, width = 210)
            self.B_GapFrame.place_forget()

            
        if selected == 'BFrame':
            self.B_GapFrame.tkraise()
            # self.subframe_BGap()
            self.B_GapFrame.place(x=30, y=70, width = 210)
            self.A_GapFrame.place_forget()


            
    def subframe_AGap(self):
            self.jobNameA_text = tk.StringVar()
            self.jobNameA_entry = tk.Entry(self.A_GapFrame, textvariable = self.jobNameA_text)
            self.jobNameA_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='news')
            self.jobNameA_text = tk.StringVar()
            self.jobNameA_entry = tk.Entry(self.A_GapFrame, textvariable = self.jobNameA_text)
            
    def subframe_BGap(self):
            
            self.jobNameB_text = tk.StringVar()
            self.jobNameB_entry = tk.Entry(self.B_GapFrame, textvariable = self.jobNameB_text)
            self.jobNameB_entry.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='news') 
            self.jobNameB_text = tk.StringVar()
            self.jobNameB_entry = tk.Entry(self.B_GapFrame, textvariable = self.jobNameB_text)
        

        

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x300+50+50")
app = Win1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just save the data to a file or database, and upon restart you can read the data in and fill in the widgets.

Comment: @BryanOakley Which database can be read out after restarting the program? can you tell me something specific?

Comment: Any database can do it, mysql? sqlite? But choosing a local database will only allow YOU to read the data, not someone else sitting else where in the world. So for that either use a remote database, or write to a txt file and read from it and append to the entry widget.

Comment: sqlite is the best thing for you to start with.